# How do I prevent the addition of the same product to the cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my E-commerce script, the same product can be added to the cart, and how do I prevent it?

```
def add
    @cart.save if @cart.new_record?
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    LineItem.create! :order => @cart, :product => product, :price => product.price
    @cart.recalculate_price!
    flash[:notice] = "Item added to cart!"
    redirect_to '/cart'
  end
```

Comment: can you please add the db schema for the models that you mention here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [uniqueness](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) validation on Cart.product_id, scoping by Cart.id:

```rb
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  validates :product_id, uniqueness: {scope: :id}
end
```

But beware of [race conditions](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/race-conditions-solution-for-rails-uniqueness-validations-a13dcee345c).

UPDATE: If no actual `Cart` model add validation to `LineItem`:

```rb
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  validates :product_id, uniqueness: {scope: :order_id}
end
```

UPDATE 2: refactor `add` method with `find_or_initialize_by`:

```rb
def add
  @cart.save if @cart.new_record?
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  line_item = LineItem.find_or_initialize_by(order:   @cart,
                                             product: product)
  line_item.price = product.price
  line_item.save!
  @cart.recalculate_price!
  flash[:notice] = "Item added to cart!"
  redirect_to '/cart'
end
```

UPDATE 3: Checking for `product` existence:

```rb
def add
  @cart.save if @cart.new_record?
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
  line_item = LineItem.find_by(order: @cart, product: product)
  if line_item
   notice = "ERROR: Product already in the cart"
  else   
   LineItem.create!(order:   @cart,
                    product: product,
                    price:   product.price)
   @cart.recalculate_price!
   notice = "Item added to cart!"
  end
  flash[:notice] = notice
  redirect_to '/cart'
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't have a cart model and a cart table. I have a lineitem table and I'm linking to my order table with order_id column

Comment: Add the validation to the LineItem model. See my update.

Comment: This works but gives 500 errors. I need to do this in the controller because the amount of the product may need to be increased. Thanks again

Comment: Do NOT validate on the controller! Use [find_or_create_by](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) instead of `create!` the line items.

Comment: works but gives an item added notice

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: I mean, if the item is in the cart, the item is already in the cart want it to give error

Comment: New (and last) update :)